# Linearization of a function

Tags: calculus

I am suppose to find the linearization of a function at a, I don't know what an a is.

$f(x) = x^4 + 3x^2, a= -1$ is an a suppose to be like a y?

Comment: $a$ is just a letter. It has no special significance, but can stand for a number. Here it stands for $-1$ (so the problem tells you), so the task is to find the linearization of the function at $-1$. In this context, "at" means that $-1$ is the argument to the function, that is, the $x$ in $x^2+3x^2$.

Comment: So why don't they just say x = -1?

Comment: It just feels like something is missing from this. I have L(x) = fprime(a)(x-a) +f(a) so I know that the problem should be $4x^3 + 6x (x-a) +2 $ but something is missing still.

Comment: You had $L(x) = f'(a) \cdot (x-a) + f(a)$ which is correct. The derivative computation $f'(x) = 4x^3+6x$ is also correct. But in the formula for "linearization", you need to plug in $f'(a)$, not $f'(x)$. Remember that finally $L(x)$ should be a linear function when considered as a function of $x$. (It will/need not be linear in $a$.)

Comment: I need to find the derivative of -1?

Comment: They could have said ‘at $x=-1$’, but they wanted to be careful to distinguish $x$, the variable, from $a$, a particular real number. Then they told you which real number $a$ is: it’s $-1$. Since it has a known value, there will be no letter $a$ anywhere in your work for this problem.

Comment: So I have three variables, y which is denoted as f(x), x which is denoted by x in this problem and a which is defined as -1. So the problem is set up as fprime(a)(x-a) + f(a) So this means that I have 0(x+1)+2?

Comment: @Jordan: No. First, $a$ isn’t a variable; it’s a constant. Secondly, $f'(\text{anything})=4\cdot\text{anything}^3+6\cdot\text{anything}$, so $f'(a)=$ ? And $f'(-1)=$ ?

Comment: I don't quite follow, the derivative of f(a) would be 0 since a is a constant and same with f(-1)

Comment: @Jordan: $f'(a)$ means that you compute the derivative $f'$ first and then evaluate it at the point $a$. I deliberately didn't mention "$x$" here, just to emphasize that it doesn't really matter what the variable is called, but if you prefer you can also phrase it as "first differentiate $f(x)$ to get $f'(x)$, then plug $x=a$ into the expression for $f'(x)$".

Comment: I don't understand what rule states that when finding the derivative of $2x^3+3x^2$ for x=2 we first make the problem $6x^2 +6x$ why not just plug in the 2 first? Why doesn't that work? I understand that it will just give us all constants which are zeroes but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's asking you to find the tangent line to its graph when $x=-1$.  To do this, you need to take it's derivative and find $f'(-1)$.  Then point-slope form for a line will give you the tangent line.

Comment: f(x)=a? Or am I wrong?

Comment: @Jordan: No, $f(x)\ne a$; $f(x)=x^4+3x^2$. The *linearization of $f$ at $a$* is, as Joe said, the tangent line to the graph of $y=x^4+3x^2$ at $x=a$. Here $a=-1$, so you’re looking for the tangent line at the point $(-1,4)$.

Comment: So x = -1 and y = f(x)

Comment: @Jordan: Sort of, but not really. In the formula $y=f(x)$, $x$ is a variable: it has no fixed value. However, you’re calculating the linearization of $f$ at a *particular* value of $x$, namely at $x=-1$. You could do the same thing at the particular value $x=a$, getting $L(x)=f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)$, and then simply substitute $-1$ for $a$ throughout; that’s what Srivatsan is explaining up above.

Comment: So I am calculating the problem a a and a is -1 and a= -1 and x= -1? So then I have fprimeof(-1)(1+1) + f(a) which is 4(-1^3) + 6(-1) (-1--1) +2?

Comment: @Jordan: Not quite. First, $f(-1)$ isn’t $2$. More important, you’re having trouble with your parentheses, and you’re confusing $x$ and $a$: $f'(a)$ is $f'(-1)=4(-1)^3+6(-1)=$  $-4-6=-10$, so $f'(a)(x-a)$ is $f'(-1)(x-(-1))=(-10)(x-(-1))=$  $(-10)(x+1)=-10x-10$.

Comment: I am getting -10x-8

Answer (score 2):

One way to think about differentiable functions is they can locally be well-approximated by lines.  Here is the function $f(x) = x^4 + 3x^2$ and the linearization (which I'll leave up to you to find):

[image]

The idea is that the tangent line at the point $(a,f(a))$ will well approximate the function $f(x)$ for $x$-values "near" $a$.  As you can see, the line really does approximate the function for $x$-values close to $-1$.  The closer the $x$-value is to $-1$, the better the line will approximate the function.  To find the linearization of a function $f(x)$ at $x = a$, there is a fancy formula in Stewart's (and to be fair, *most* other texts on the subject of) calculus.  However, this formula really just wants you to find the tangent line of the function $f(x)$ at the point $(a,f(a))$.  The slope of this tangent line is given by $f'(a)$ by the **definition** of the derivative, and the slope and point $(a, f(a))$ are enough to give you the equation of the line.

Comment: Well it is beyond frustrating to be working on this single problem for the better part of a day.

Comment: Frustration is a different story, and it is normal.  If a problem causes you to get this upset, I would suggest putting down the problem, and revisiting it at another time.

Comment: I don't have that kind of time and I attempt to. I just wish people like Stewart weren't so arrogant about math and tried to explain things in a way that people who aren't amazing at math can learn from.

Answer (score 1):

The "linearization of $f(x)$" means "the linear function which best approximates $f(x)$."  The graph of a linear function is a line, while $f(x)$ can look pretty weird.  So no linear function is going to look like $f$ everywhere.  But if we choose some point on the graph of $f(x)$ -- that is, if we look at "the linearization of $f(x)$ at -1" -- we can get a good linear approximation of $f(x)$ near that point.

The thing is, the linearization of $f(x)$ is also a function, which you've written $L(x)$.  It might get confusing to talk about "the linearization of f(x) at x = -1" because both $L$ and $f$ use $x$ as a variable.  So we usually talk about the linearization at $a$, which is a perfectly fine letter.

You start with $f(x) = x^4 + 3x^2$, and you want to find its linearization at $a = 1$.  You already have a formula for it: $L(x) = f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)$.

$f'(a) = 4a^3 + 6a$ and $f'(-1) = -4 - 6 = -10$.  So $L(x) = -10(x - (-1)) + f(-1) = -10(x+1) + 4$.

Comment: I don't follow those last two lines at all.

Comment: The derivative of $f$ is a function.  I assume you know how to calculate $f'(x) = 4x^3 + 6x$.  Well, if we want to calculate the value of $f'(x)$ when $x = -1$, we calculate $f(-1) = -4 - 6 = -10$.

Comment: So -10(-1--1)+2?

Comment: I don't know what you mean -- tell me more.

Comment: I have L(x) = fprime(a)(x-a) +f(a) and a= -1 and x=a so I have -10(-1--1)+2

Comment: $x$ and $a$ are different!  $x$ is a variable.  $a$ is a constant which happens to be written with a letter.  The linearization of $f(x)$ will be a *function* of $x$, not a number.

Comment: So then I have -10(x+1)+2? Or -10x-8?

Comment: Why $+2$?  The algebra works out to $+4$.

Comment: I get -2 no matter what.

Comment: $f(-1) =  (-1)^4 + 3(-1)^2 = 1 + 3 = 4$, no?

Comment: No...I am getting 2. -1^4 is -1+3=2

Comment: Uh, $(-1)^4 = (-1)\times(-1)\times(-1)\times(-1) = 1$.

Comment: My calculator keeps giving me 2.

Comment: Doing it again I got -2, which I think is proper. -1 to a positive power should be 1, and then 3 times -1 to a positive power will be 3 3+1=4 but my calculator won't give me that answer even with proper parantheses.

Comment: Your difficulties might lie more with algebra than calculus.  You ought to be able to compute $(-1)^4 = 1$ by hand or in your head.  In any case, you're either inputting the wrong thing into your calculator or your calculator is wrong.

Comment: I think my calculator assumes $-1^2$ is going to be -(1^2) for some reaosn.

Comment: So I should just stop doing this homework, spend a couple weeks brushing up on algebra and then fail this class? I don't see that as an option really.

Comment: @Jordan "I think my calculator assumes $−1^2$ is going to be -(1^2) for some reaosn." - Most people follow exactly the same convention the calculator follows. If you want to specify $(-1)^4$, you should clearly put the paranthesis around $-1$.